# WPF - Display combination of contents(images, video, text)

Tags: wpf

I’m trying to display contents. Contents can be a combination of image, video & text. Each one of them has a start date time & end date time.
I could display one image using  tag but I couldn’t display series of images in a loop. Its displaying only last image or video. Immediate help appreciated.
Code snippet as follows -

```
// Check if Content if its an Image
if (dataTable.Rows[nCnt][1].Equals("I"))
{
     imageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(strContent));
     Image1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                Image1.Source = imageSource;
}
else
    // Check if Content if its an Video
    if (dataTable.Rows[nCnt][1].Equals("V"))
    {
          MyVideo1.Source = new Uri(strContent);
          MyVideo1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
          MyVideo1.Play();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are filling the same image and video container(Image1, MyVideo1), with diferent images and videos. So the last one is the only one displayed. You should create a collection of images and videos. `List<YourMediaType>` or `ObservableCollection<YourMediaType>` if you are using MVVM.